# How to plot 4 separate lines to form a square in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting 4 random separate lines in a plot, and I want them to be connected to form a square. This is what I've got so far, any pointers would be really helpful. Also, this is my first time using MATLAB so please don't come for me.

```
N = 1;
L = 0.2;


x = L +rand(1,N)*(1-2*L);
y = L +rand(1,N)*(1-2*L);


angs = rand(1,N)*360;

xe = x - L*cosd(angs);
ye = y + L*sind(angs);
xb = -x - L*cosd(angs);
yb = y +  L*sind(angs);

ax = axes;

plot(ax,[x;xe],[y;ye],[x;xb],[y;yb])

axis square
```

I need them to be 4 lines of the same length that join to make a square. The above code gives me 2 connecting lines but I really don't know where to go from there.

My attempt of the above code:
[image: My attempt of the above code]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Regarding _Please don't come for me_: if you get a downvote, it is not against _you_, it simply means that _your question_ does not show effort, is unclear or not useful (according to the downvoter). The fact that this is your _first time using MATLAB_ is irrelevant. Questions and answers are voted on, not people

Comment: I suggest you use a call to plot for each line, with `hold on`, simply beause you are using the plot function wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function simply plots the x- and y- coordinates that you give it. Giving it the correct coordinates to plot is your job. So how would you figure out the coordinates of a square, given a starting point and the length and direction of one of the sides?

Suppose we have

```
p0 = rand(1, 2); % p0(1) => x; p0(2) => y
L = 10;
d0 = rand(1, 2); % The direction vector.
```

First, let's convert the direction into a unit vector.

```
u_vec = d0 ./ norm(d0);
```

Next, let's rotate this vector by 90 degrees to get the unit vector for the perpendicular side

```
u_perp = ([0, -1; 1 0] * u_vec')';
```

Using vector addition, we know that the second point is `p1 = p0 + L * u_vec`. The third point is `p2 = p1 + L * u_perp`, and the final point is `p3 = p_0 + L * u_perp`. We can stack these vectors just to make it easier to type out the plotting code:

```
l1 = [p0; p1];
l2 = [p1; p2];
l3 = [p2; p3];
l4 = [p3; p0];
```

And finally plot them:

```
figure();
hold on;
plot(l1(:, 1), l1(:, 2));
plot(l2(:, 1), l2(:, 2));
plot(l3(:, 1), l3(:, 2));
plot(l4(:, 1), l4(:, 2));
axis square;
```

[image]

Or, you could stack everything into one array and plot using a single line:

```
sq = [p0; p1; p2; p3; p0];
figure();
plot(sq(:, 1), sq(:, 2));
axis square;
```

[image]